# How can I disable these log messages in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting TONS of these messages when generating a PDF with Jasper now:

INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'stackedAreaType': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireCandidate=true; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireCandidate=true; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Sep 26, 2011 10:42:57 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition

Obviously I need to set the log level somewhere, just not sure of the command. Any help is appreciated! I am not a Java expert, I use JR embedded in a Ruby app to give my customers nice PDFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Jasper specifically but this is the generic approach.  You need to change the log4j root log level.

Look for a file log4j.properties.  Find a line that looks like:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO
```

Replace INFO for WARN.  Restart your server process.

Comment: I bet it's buried in one of these JARs.

Comment: It may just be if you are blessed with a usual enterprise mish-mash java application.  I'd hope they ship the properties file separately for your sake.

Comment: It's a mishmash alright. I'll have to rebuild those jars from source. Maybe later...

Comment: Good luck - may the force be with you etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I run a java program from the commandline, that program outputs a pdf to stdout where PHP redirects it to browser, and some library(spring.jar) was outputting lots of INFO that crippled the pdf output, I tried running the java commandline with `java -Dlog4j.rootCategory=WARN` but for some reason it didn't work, so I finally solved it by setting the logging level programatically:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
logger.setLevel(Level.WARN);
```

Make sure you have log4j-1.2.16.jar in your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using both of the answers listed here. I created a log4j.properties file and added this in it:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN
```

But I also had to add log4j in my classpath.